# PHP mktime and add time

Tags: php, datetime

```
<?php date("Y-m-d H:i:s",mktime(0,0,0), time() + $cas * 1800); ?>
```

This gives me error

> Warning: date() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given in /www/graf/fill_database/fill_database.php on line 8.

How can i do this with these functions.

Comment: What you actually want to achieve over here. Post your input along with expected output

Comment: add 30 minutes to time 0:0:0

Comment: Pass the appropriate arguments to `mktime`, not to `date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I don't use mktime more than 5 years, because there is better solutions.
2. I use Carbon, because it's super library that fits all my needs with time/date operations. https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon
3. And here is the answer:

Read manual: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php

> string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )

and this is solution:

```
<?= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + $cas * 1800); ?>
```

4. maybe You want get date time from beginning of current day?

so:

```
<?= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00')) + $cas * 1800); ?>
```

Comment: this is server time not 00:00:00 so this isn't the solution.